# Length of field content does not match the content-length attribute

Tags: tds

I am facing an issue during syncing of item using TDS into Sitecore, the issue is given below

```
> Error reading item:
> /sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/PageSettings/Tabs/Custom
> Tab
> 
> Length of field content does not match the content-length attribute.
> Field name: __Renderings, field id:
> {F1A1FE9E-A60C-4DDB-A3A0-BB5B29FE732E}
```

I followed various blog post which as given below.

https://www.coreysmith.co/hedgehog-tds-field-content-does-not-match-content-length/

http://seankearney.com/post/Using-Team-Development-for-Sitecore-with-GitHub

But still, the problem persists, Please help, if you have an idea.

Comment: What version of tds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in document which you are following you need to `*.item -text` this line into `.gitattributes` file. Then try to reload your solution. It should work.

Comment: I think you mean `.gitattributes`

Comment: updated thanks.